# How we can call an ajax url with angular 2.0 in node

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new in angular 2.0 And I am trying to call an ajax.But i could not call an ajax on button click. Please help i implement following code

```
import {Component,enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './templates/login.html'})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
}
```

Comment: [Http Client docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax call i am understanding as HTTP call/calling HTTP Api. you can call your api like this.

```
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
       let res = this.getHeroes();
       console.log(res);
  }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get('http//api.example.com/api/url/here')
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json())
               .catch(console.log);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Html,

```
 <button (click) = 'getstudentbyid(121)'>CLICK</button>
```

ts,

```
    import {Component,enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './templates/login.html'})
    export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

     getstudentbyid(id: any): any {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3009/api/auth/getstudentbyid/' + id, { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result.json().error_code == 0) {
                    this.res = result.json().result;
                    this.students = this.res;
                }
                else {
                    this.students = result.json().result;
                }
            })
    }
}
```